# Is there any disadvantage of weighting variables in forecasting multivariate time using RNN?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, deep-learning, loss-functions, recurrent-neural-network

I am doing time series prediction for Temperature based on time-series data of Temperature and Humidity. Since, I want prediction only for Temperature I have weighted Temperature ten-times so that in my loss function temperature should have more importance and temperature related weights train faster.

Is there any flaw or disadvantage in using this technique?

Comment: Why not just have a loss function only for temperature?

Comment: @AlexR. : Because I am predicting for next n timesteps and to do so I need (n-1) prediction as input for next prediction, that's why I have to predict both Temperature and Humidity. For that, I think I need to optimize both. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your inputs at time t are $(T_t,H_t)$, the temperature and humidity, but your prediction at each timestep is $T_{t+1}$. That's fine. But, you have full control over what your loss function is, so you can just measure the loss on your sequence $T_1,T_2,...$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because you are taking still **humidity** into account, even with a smaller weight. So your loss function is like:

$L_n = F(T_n,H_n)$

Consider for example a dataset where **humidity** has a *very high variation* and **temperature** is *roughly constant*, let's say it's changes are negligible and **temperature** value is close to $C$ - the model you train on this dataset will react to **humidity** changes, not the **temperature**.

$L_n = F(T_n,H_n) \approx F(C,H_n) = F(H_n)$

Last equality is based on the fact that $C$ is just a constant. This is not what you want to have, no?

The only way to do it correctly is to calculate your loss function based only on **temperature**:

$L_n = F(T_n)$

From what you said in comments I understand that in the next timestep **temperature** is somehow a function of **humidity** and **temperature** from the previous timestep. That is ok and independent of your loss function.

$T_n = F(T_{n-1}, H_{n-1})$